# OpenConnect Server not connecting to internet using ufw ip forwarding

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, iptables, openconnect

I want to create an OpenConnect VPN server. I followed [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openconnect-vpn-server-ocserv-ubuntu-20-04-lets-encrypt) tutorial step by step however, while I'm able to connect to the open connect server using a client, the problem is that **I don't have any access to internet** (on the client side) after connecting to the server.
I figured this should be an IP forwarding issue. This is the steps I took to setup the ipforwarding:

1. enable ip forwarding using these three commands:

   - `echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/60-custom.conf`
   - `echo "net.core.default_qdisc=fq" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/60-custom.conf`
   - `echo "net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=bbr" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.d/60-custom.conf`
   - and finally `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/60-custom.conf`
2. configured ufw *before.rules* and added the following:

   ```
   # NAT table rules
   *nat
   :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
   -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

   # End each table with the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
   COMMIT

   # allow forwarding for trusted network
   -A ufw-before-forward -s 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   -A ufw-before-forward -d 10.10.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
   ```
3. Finally I restarted and enabled the ufw.

However, when I type `sudo iptables -t nat -L POSTROUTING` instead of showing me something like this:
[image]

it shows me this:

[image]

I have no idea why it is adding those `.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal` to the end of the ips. Could it be because of this?
Note that I'm using an AWS vps (I've checked lightsail firewall as well), Ubuntu 20 os, and the latest version of ocserv. I'm also forwarding all the traffic including DNS through the VPN.
The ocserv config is as follows:

```
auth = "plain[passwd=/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd]"
tcp-port = 443

## Comands for SSL/TLS certifications

try-mtu-discovery = true
cert-user-oid = 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1
compression = true
default-domain = sub.mydomain.xyz
ipv4-network = 10.10.10.0
ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0
ipv6-subnet-prefix = 64
tunnel-all-dns = true
dns = 8.8.8.8
dns = 1.1.1.1
#route = 10.0.0.0/8
#route = 172.16.0.0/12
#route = 192.168.0.0/16
#route = fd00::/8
#route = default
```

And here are the results of the tracert to my server (from client).

```
Tracing route to sub.mydomain.xyz [x.x.x.x]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    43 ms    42 ms    43 ms  100.101.0.1
  3    44 ms    42 ms    42 ms  172.19.16.65
  4    43 ms    44 ms     *     172.19.17.73
  5    46 ms    44 ms     *     172.19.17.41
  6    47 ms    45 ms    44 ms  10.202.6.192
  7    48 ms    45 ms    44 ms  10.21.212.10
  8   118 ms   116 ms   115 ms  85.132.90.169
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10   130 ms   166 ms   140 ms  188.43.209.206
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16   267 ms   273 ms   267 ms  101.203.89.179
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19   291 ms   363 ms   357 ms  54.239.52.99
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22   298 ms   294 ms   294 ms  54.239.122.82
 23   296 ms   297 ms   301 ms  52.93.248.146
 24   297 ms   326 ms   362 ms  52.93.248.149
 25   303 ms   296 ms   316 ms  54.239.122.109
 26   304 ms   310 ms   390 ms  54.239.122.4
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Comment: Don't worry about `.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal`, it is not in the iptables configuration, but what gives you your DNS. `sudo iptables -t nat -n -L POSTROUTING` should avoid the DNS resolution. Could you indicate more elements about the client side ? is it a client on your LAN, on Internet ? what is its routing table ? what print a `traceroute` to Internet ?

Comment: The client side is a windows pc, and I have used the AnyConnect program to connect to other servers (with internet access) just fine. I have also tested an iOS client, and the same issue was present. No, the client is not on LAN; it is over the Internet. Basic Windows firewall rules (output ports are open and no specified routings). I also added the result of tracert.

Comment: It looks like you DO have internet connection, judging by the tracert output. Did you try to manually set up DNS server? Also, it'd seem then the route fails at a server in North Korea, which might be blocked on the next hop. Have you tried using another ISP? ( on your client side )

Comment: I think you should `tcpdump` on the server. Also it's better to post the full `iptables-save` dump (without *pointless* redaction on [*private* IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)). Btw, does `-o eth0` even actually suit your server's case?